# The images or media from CD returns http instead of https on Sitecore

Tags: jss

I have setup Sitecore JSS project from Getting Started template and I am using XP1 topology with CD and CM on separate containers to simulate actual production environment. However my problem is the images or media returns in HTTP instead of HTTPS, that will cause the images unable to load.

[image]

Below are the source returns:

[image]

It is working on CM and Experience Editor but it does not work when I publish and view from CD.

Snippet from rendering server, I print out the content of the fields:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SSE, Faizal. Since you are using JSS, your website is served from rendering host container. May I know why are you using CD instance here ?

Comment: Hi Vikrant. I am new with JSS/Sitecore and I use XP1 for my docker compose setup. I'm using ImageField to retrieve the Image from Sitecore and it translated to the URL from CD as above. Is this not a correct approach?


<NextImage field={props.fields.image.value} height="50" width="200" />

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to set the **IncludeServerUrlInMediaUrls** to false for the layoutservice you are using - something like this:

```
<layoutService>
  <configurations>
    <config name="default">
        <rendering>
            <renderingContentsResolver>
                <IncludeServerUrlInMediaUrls>false</IncludeServerUrlInMediaUrls>
            </renderingContentsResolver>
      </rendering>
    </config>
    <config name="jss">
      <rendering>
        <renderingContentsResolver>
          <IncludeServerUrlInMediaUrls>false</IncludeServerUrlInMediaUrls>
        </renderingContentsResolver>
      </rendering>
    </config>
    <config name="sxa-jss">
      <rendering>
        <renderingContentsResolver>
          <IncludeServerUrlInMediaUrls>false</IncludeServerUrlInMediaUrls>
        </renderingContentsResolver>
      </rendering>
     </config>
  </configurations>
</layoutService>
```

This way you should get relative urls in the graphql output.

Comment: it works! Thank you

Comment: No problem - don't forget to mark the answer as accepted ;)

Comment: The answer works, however got a few comments:
1. For XM Cloud you need to set false only config name="sxa-jss", there was no mention to it in the documentation, so I tried the above patch but for other onfig - JSS which obviously did not work. "sxa-jss" is the one that is in use; 
2. Still wondering why protocol generates as HTTP rather than HTTPS, when not using relative path